# Is there a theorem that describes the computation of characteristic polynomial of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
b & a 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then instantly I find that my characteristic polynomial is:

$P(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - a\lambda - b$

Expand this matrix to be

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
a & b & c 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Boom

$P(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - a\lambda^2 - b\lambda - c$

Is there a theorem that governs this result?

Comment: There is a theorem that states that the characteristic polynomial of the companion matrix ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix ) of a polynomial $P$ is $P$ itself. In your case, your $A$ is the transpose of the companion matrix of $P$, but clearly taking the transpose does not change the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Maybe you can show it by induction?